# How to run command line from Delphi?

Tags: delphi

How can I run this command from my Delphi application?

> C:\myapppath\appfolder>appname.exe /stext save.txt

I tried the following code:

```
ShellExecute(0, nil, 'cmd.exe', 'cd C:\myapppath\appfolder', nil, SW_Hide);
ShellExecute(0, nil, 'cmd.exe', 'appname.exe /stext save.txt', nil, SW_Hide);
```

But it didn't work. Can anyone provide a solution?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To run a CMD command, you need to use the `/C` flag of `cmd.exe`:

```
ShellExecute(0, nil, 'cmd.exe', '/C cd C:\myapppath\appfolder', nil, SW_HIDE);
ShellExecute(0, nil, 'cmd.exe', '/C appname.exe /stext save.txt', nil, SW_HIDE);
```

However, this will create two different sessions, so it will not work. But you can use ShellExecute to run `appname.exe` directly, like so:

```
ShellExecute(0, nil, 'appname.exe',  '/stext save.txt', nil, SW_HIDE);
```

But you need to specify the filenames properly.

I would do

```
var
  path: string;

begin
  path := ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName);
  ShellExecute(0, nil, PChar(Application.ExeName), PChar('/stext "' + path + 'save.txt"'), nil, SW_HIDE);
end;
```

in case `appname.exe` is the current application. Otherwise, replace `Application.ExeName` with the full path of `appname.exe`.

Comment: WS_HIDE should be SW_HIDE. I tried to edit it, but received the message: Edits must be at least 6 characters...