# How to execute MSBuild from Delphi?

Tags: delphi, batch-file, command-line, msbuild

I'm working on automating our software's build / deploy process. One major piece of this is executing `msbuild` to compile multiple Delphi projects.

Following numerous resources [such as this one](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Building_a_Project_Using_an_MSBuild_Command), I can do it successfully from the RAD Studio Command Line (which is simply calling `rsvars.bat` to set some environment variables). However, when trying to automate both this batch file and the `msbuild` command from Delphi, I cannot figure out how to proceed.

The key of the issue is that the batch file and the actual `msbuild` command are two entirely separate commands - although they need to be run together under the same environment. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378896/how-to-run-command-line-from-delphi) somewhat related, but I don't see a clear answer for my scenario.

How can I execute `msbuild` from Delphi while first preparing it with the environment variables as found in `rsvars.bat`?

Comment: If it were me I would port rsvars to Delphi and create msbuild process directly

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3378909/65863) showed, you can run `cmd.exe` itself with command-line parameters to execute commands.

Per the [cmd.exe documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771320.aspx):

> Syntax
>
> ```
> cmd [/c|/k] [/s] [/q] [/d] [/a|/u] [/t:{<B><F>|<F>}] [/e:{on|off}] [/f:{on|off}] [/v:{on|off}] [<String>]
> ```
>
> Parameters
>
> /c
>   Carries out the command specified by *String* and then stops.
>   ...
>   <String>
>   Specifies the command you want to carry out.
>   ...
>
> Remarks
>
> - Using multiple commands
>
>   To use multiple commands for <String>, separate them by the command separator **&&** and enclose them in quotation marks. For example:
>
>   ```
>   "<Command>&&<Command>&&<Command>"
>   ```
> - Processing quotation marks
>
>   If you specify **/c** or **/k**, cmd processes the remainder of *String*, and quotation marks are preserved only if all of the following conditions are met:
>
>   - You do not use **/s**.
>   - You use exactly one set of quotation marks.
>   - You do not use any special characters within the quotation marks (for example: `& < > ( ) @ ^ |` ).
>   - You use one or more white-space characters within the quotation marks.
>   - The *String* within quotation marks is the name of an executable file.
>
>   If the previous conditions are not met, *String* is processed by examining the first character to verify whether it is an opening quotation mark. If the first character is an opening quotation mark, it is stripped along with the closing quotation mark. Any text following the closing quotation marks is preserved.

So try using `CreateProcess()` or `ShellExecute/Ex()` to run an instance of `cmd.exe` with these parameters:

```
cmd.exe /C ""<path>\rsvars.bat" && msbuild "<path>\project" <msbuild parameters> ..."
```

---

Alternatively, you can have your app load `rsvars.bat` and parse out the values it defines (or just define the values in your own code), and then execute `msbuild` using `CreateProcess()`, passing the desired environment variables to its `lpEnvironment` parameter.  This way, you do not need to actually execute `rsvars.bat` at all.

Comment: Are the quotes supposed to be wrapped around all parameters? I think that's what's throwing me off, because some of the parameters themselves have their own quotes around the full path/filename values.

Comment: @JerryDodge: Per the documentation I posted, the entire `<String>` needs to be in quotes in order to use `&&`, and the individual commands can have their own quoted parameters as well. I updated my answer with a larger quote of the documentation.

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick. However now I'm pursuing how to completely ignore the `rsvars.bat` file altogether, and call `msbuild` directly.

Comment: Well, you can't ignore it, since it does define some important environment variables that Delphi projects actually use. But you don't need to execute `rsvars.bat` itself to give those variables to msbuild, you can pass them directly to `CreateProcess()` instead.

Comment: That's what I meant, ignore the actual file itself, and just implement the same thing directly in my application. I also re-worded my question so that I'm asking for any alternative possibility besides including `rsvars.bat`.

Comment: I gave you an alternative at the end of my answer.

Comment: Indeed, and that's exactly what I'm pursuing now.

Answer (score 5):

Another way which works is to put both commands together into another new batch file. This also allows you to build multiple projects using the same environment. For example `DoBuild.bat` with the following contents:

```
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\bin\rsvars.bat"
msbuild "<path>\MyProject.dproj"
msbuild "<path>\MyOtherProject.dproj"
msbuild "<path>\YetAnotherProject.dproj"
```

Then, just execute your batch file:

```
Cmd.exe /K "<path>\DoBuild.bat"
```

Comment: If you use `/C`, `cmd.exe` terminates after the command is finished.  If you use `/K` instead, it keeps running.